# Thread spin-waits on time to pass error

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

Why does this happen with ehcache (latest version)? What should be done to get rid of this issue? This issue occurs when I am trying to do bulk upload of data.

```
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 57 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 58 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 59 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 60 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 61 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 62 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 63 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 64 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 65 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 66 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 67 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 68 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 69 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 70 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 71 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 72 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 73 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 74 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 75 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 76 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 77 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 78 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 79 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
14:38:52,359 INFO [Timestamper] Thread spin-waits on time to pas
s. Looped 80 times, you might want to increase -Dnet.sf.ehcache.u
til.Timestamper.shift
```

Comment: I am using 2.4.6 and have same error

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an [Ehcache bug](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-853?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel) which has been fixed in version 2.4.3.

Comment: Unable to download 2.4.3 via maven, will check it out shortly

Comment: Do you know when 2.4.3 will be available?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. You might try using the trunk (at least you'll get a confirmation whether this is indeed the problem) or asking on their forums.